# IE even Chrome is occassionally not populating the time with jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I had thought this code was working great. Then a B.A. tested my code and said that the Time is getting cut off, that I looked at what they saved and it was not getting cut off, it is literally getting chopped off.  I could not reproduce in Chrome and decided to pull up IE and sure enough I reproduced it. Then I tried later and IE worked fine.  Another person at first both IE and Chrome didn't show the complete Time , but then once they refreshed their browser they cannot reproduce.  Neither can I.

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/xf12y7y4/2/

```
function setDateTimeOn(elm,stormTime) {
        var formattedDate = GetCurrentDateTime(); //get formatted date
        $(elm) //clicked button
            .parent("td") // container td
            .next() // next td
            .find("span")
            .text(formattedDate);  // set date    must use .text for the span (label renders as a span)

        var id = $(elm).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
        var storm = $('#hdnPage').val();

        console.log(formattedDate);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(stormTime);
        console.log(storm);

        setStormTimes(id, storm, stormTime, formattedDate);

    }

    function GetCurrentDateTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var h12 = hours12(now);
        return (now.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
            + now.getDate() + "-"
            + now.getFullYear() + " "
            + now.getHours() + ":" 
            + now.getMinutes();
    }
```

Seems that the problem is with

```
now.getMinutes()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, but note that when the minutes value is less that 10 you'll get only one digit.

Comment: not getting cut off...numbers in javascript don't return leading `0`.. add that padding yourself

Comment: Other than poorly wording the question, it's got a blurb of code, the bad output, and a link to a fiddle. This is a good question, no reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now.getMinutes()` is returning a value between 0 and 59, so when it returns 0 through 9, your formatting is broken since something like 12:03 is formatted as 12:3. To fix it simply pad with a 0:

```
("0" + now.getMinutes()).substr(-2); // replace now.getMinutes();
```

Comment: I am using the code you show here, I do understand what you are saying, but I don't understand why it is working 99% of the time no matter what minute it is.

Comment: OH WAIT,  so in the image that I pasted,  10:1   =  10:10  ?  right?  and it is getting cut off?   if so , that makes sense then

Comment: @BrianThornton no; the opposite: 10:1 is what's displayed for 10:01. The leading 0 isn't shown because `now.getMinutes()` returns a single digit if the return value is a single digit.